# PHP can't find uploaded file comes from android

Tags: java, php, android, ubuntu

I tried to upload an image to server via php using this [website](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/) . 
When i check if($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"])!="") it will return false. Is it because of the php server permission?

Comment: it can be so, what is in $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error''] ? Check also the file_uploads, upload_max_filesize, upload_tmp_dir, post_max_size and max_input_time directives in php.ini

Comment: I tried to get buffersize it prints 0. I have check $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'']>0 if $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"])!=""